# Flush RSS Cache

Tags: rss, cache

I'm editing my RSS feed by adding extra elements containing custom fields I've created. I'm aware these won't work on standard RSS readers, but I've building a custom page for a different website that I'm in control of so I can ensure they will be displayed.

As I'm regularly needing to see the out put of the RSS XML I'm struggling with the RSS cache. I can't find a method of flushing it.

I've tried this in my functions.php

```
    function return_cache_time( $seconds ){
        // change the default feed cache recreation period to 60 seconds
        return (int) 60;
    }
    //set feed cache duration
    add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', 'return_cache_time');
```

I've also tried changing my config.php by adding this

```
    define( 'MAGPIE_CACHE_AGE', 10 ); // Cache RSS feeds for only 10 seconds
```

Neither seemed to work.

I had a little poke around the `wp_options` table in the database but couldn't find anything that looked like the RSS cache.

I'm running Wordpress 4.1.

What is the correct way to decrease the cache time for the RSS feed?

How can I clear the current RSS cache?

Comment: Unknowingly, I had 2 versions of my functions.php file open and the one with my changes wasn't being saved correctly.

Every time I adjust the XML feed the RSS is rebuilt automatically.

Comment: So is your issue resolved then? Please consider adding what had worked for you as an answer.